# How to remove this naming activity warning from manifest?

Tags: android, warnings, manifest

It warns to use "$" instead of "." but when I am using "." it turns into error.

````
            <activity android:name=".Activity.SettingsActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".Activity.EnterPinActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".Activity.FirstPinActivity" />```
````

Comment: For which Class ? Are both of your classes extends From Activity and Are Concrete  classes ?

Comment: yes all four are extends from activity

Comment: @MikeM.  thanks I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the package with small letter. Package name should not be Capital letters

```
activity instead of Activity
```

then it should be like this

```
<activity android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity" />
```

rename like this all packages.
 Class name should be capital its not problem.

Answer (score 0):

The dotted naming convention is used as package naming convention.

Check if your Activities files are in the `Activity` package. If not, put the right package name instead

Comment: yes all my activities are in the activity package and working correctly but how to remove this warning.